# Android Activity is started in application process though its starting from other process

Tags: android, process

I have 3 activities in my android app:

```
MainActivity, FirstActivity , SecondActivity
```

in the `FirstActivity` Manifest I start other process using `"android:process=":testprocess"`

now my calling sequence is as followes

```
Mainactivity->Starts FirstActivity

FirstActivity->starts SecondActivity
```

I verified  the `pid` in `onResume` of all the three activity

```
 Mainactivity and SecondActivity showing same pid"17256"

 FirstActivity showing pid "17826"
```

but I want **SecondaActivity** also to be part of **process FirstActivity**, I need to achieve this without mentioning `"android:process=":testprocess"` for the `SecondActivity` in android manifest

Comment: **Vote up answers that are helpful . Users will also vote on answers to your question.**

`Accept it. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.`